# "Bloquear" uma lib em determinada parte do código

Tags: php, html, css, lib

No meu código estou com uma lib do materialize porém ela começa a aplicar css que não quero em determinada parte do meu código, existe uma maneira de "Bloquear" ela nessa determinada parte?

Comment: Mas se tirar as classes do Materialize, não resolve?

Comment: Infelizmente não, já tentei :/

Comment: Guilherme, dá uma melhorada na pergunta. Posta um código simples com o exemplo. Só para ficar mais completa, exata. Dei +1 porque até eu quero saber se isso é possível! rs ✌️